# The page isn't redirecting properly after MVC 3 deploy

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm deploy my MVC 3 application to a server and, after solve several issues related with missing MVC dlls (the server does not have MVC installed) it start to give a error:

**Firefox** "The page isn't redirecting properly"
**Chrome** "This webpage has a redirect loop"
**IE** "This page can't be displayed"

I found people saying that it is something cookie related, but I can't understand how to solve the problem.

I never see the default page whether.

I suspect there is a problem with my Global.asax file or my Web.Config.

**Global.asax**:

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
    }

    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );

    }

    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }

}
```

And there is a part of my **Web.Config** without AppSettings, connectionStrings and system.serviceModel:

```
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" defaultLanguage="c#" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Helpers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.WebPages, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
    <customErrors mode="Off">
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="/Error/PageNotFound" />
    </customErrors>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <handlers>
      <remove name="UrlRoutingHandler" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```

**Index** action from Login page:

```
public ActionResult Index()
 {
   if (CurrentAuthenticatedData != null && CurrentAuthenticatedData.User != null)
     ViewBag.IsLogin = true;
   else
     ViewBag.IsLogin = false;

     return View();
  }
```

**CurrentAuthenticatedData**:

```
System.Web.Routing.RequestContext Ctx = null;
public AuthenticatedData CurrentAuthenticatedData
{
    get
    {
        AuthenticatedData retval = null;

        if (Ctx.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            retval = (AuthenticatedData)ViewBag.Auth;
        }

        return retval;
    }
}
```

AuthenticatedData is a class where I store several attributes related to logged user.

And finally my **View** code:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Efetuar Login</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    <div style="@(ViewBag.IsLogin??false ? "display: none" : "")">
        @Html.ValidationMessage("Error")
        <p>Username:<input type="text" name="usr" /></p>
        <p>Password:<input type="password" name="pwd" /></p>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Login" />
        </p> 
    </div>
}
```

I try to deploy a dummie MVC application and it works! =/

Can you help me?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post back your index(Action) method ?? May be your code is creating loop .

Comment: @surajsingh I edit my first post with this information

Comment: View Please it might give some idea!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discover that MVC runs a method called **Initialize**, in my BaseController, before any other:

```
protected override void Initialize(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext)
{
  ...
}
```

Inside that method I has a verification to know if user is authenticated and when not I do a `Session.Abandon();` and a strange thing (I don't know why):

```
if (!requestContext.HttpContext.Request.CurrentExecutionFilePath.Equals("/MyWebSite/"))
  Response.Redirect("~/", true);
```

It runs me into a infinite loop because the request page was **MyNewWebsite** insted MyWebSite...

Sorry and thank you for your patience

Answer (score 2):

There's probably a problem with your MVC installation. Make sure you install MVC correctly.

I'm guessing that your routes are not properly registered and thus if you go to your app's home page it will show you a 404. This gets picked up by this line in the web.config:

```
<error statusCode="404" redirect="/Error/PageNotFound" />
```

and redirects you to that page, which also throws a 404, redirecting you again to the same page, and so on and so on, causing the redirect loop.

For debugging purposes, you could comment out that line and check whether your routes are registered or not.

Comment: As I said "the server does not have MVC installed" but I copy the proper dll files and I actually make a MVC 3 application works in the server, in the same website (just replace my application files for a new dummie MVC application file) an it works. Comment the line you suggest don't make any progresse in my problem. Same page appears, but thanks anyway.